# Dragging element horizontally by 100px increments

Tags: javascript, html, css, vue.js

I'm having a hard time figuring this out.

I have a bunch of `div`s (with some content inside them), and I want to be able to drag and drop them, horizontally. However, I want to move them by 100px increments (the `left` position needs to be 0, 100, 200 etc). Imagine having a table in the background with 100px wide cells and you can only move the element to another cell. Except there's no table.

jQuery is out of the question I think (I'm using Vue).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I won't write your code for you, but I'll help you figure it out by telling you where to start.

---

First, listen to the `mousedown` and `mouseup` events on the element:

```html
<div v-on="{ mousedown, mouseup }">Some content</div>
```

Next register a `mousemove` listener on `mousedown`, and deregister it on `mouseup`:

```js
methods: {
    mousemove(e) {
        const moved = e.offsetX - this.startX;
        // The mouse has moved "moved" pixels.
        // Now calculate whatever you want 
    },
    mousedown(e) {
        this.startX = e.offsetX;

        e.currentTarget.addEventListener(this.mousemove);
    },
    mouseup(e) {
        e.currentTarget.removeEventListener(this.mousemove);
    },
}
```

Comment: Yeah I've been experimenting with this and checking the offset difference seems to work well. Cheers